# Javascript Bookmarklet :Invisible Tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, bookmarklet, chromebook

I was wondering if anybody knew a Javascript Bookmarklet to make a tab go invisible? For example, Javascript:. I looked around Stackoverflow and the web. I am using a Chromebook. My browser in Chrome and I really need help.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: To like hide a tab

Comment: tab go invisible? What tab?

Comment: I mean if it's possible to make the tab smaller or bigger. If I could shrink it using Javascript:. Sorry if I didn't use enough information.

Comment: Any tab basiclly.

Comment: I can change the tab's name, but I was wondering if I could make it hide/show.

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Ok that helps. I can stop doing research thanks:)

Answer (score -1):

```
javascript:(function() {
    var link = document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']") || document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/x-icon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = 'https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/infinite_arrow_favicon_5.ico';
    document.title='My Drive - Google Drive';
    console.log(document.title);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);https://twitter.com/TitaniumNetwerk
})();
```

Comment: bookmark a site, and put this script in the name of the bookmark.

Comment: @SnipeHammer08 .